# Can you explain this odd behavior with dragging items into nested sortables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following setup:

- A sortable list where one of the `<li>` has a table with lists in each cell.
- All of the lists are sortable with each other.
- Draggable items that can be added to any of the sortables

Issue: When adding a draggable item ('drag 1', 'drag 2', 'drag 3') to one of the lists in the horizontal lists (table of lists) it duplicates the draggable when dropped.  Sometimes it will create both copies in the same list or one in the item list and one in the column list.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MQTgA/

Question: How do I prevent the second item being created when dropping the draggable?

**UPDATE**: With changing the class names of the horizontal lists to something else ('hlist') and omitting the new class name from the 'connectToSortable' option ('ul.hlist'), it no longer drops two copies and still allows the item to be dropped in any list.  This doesn't seem right.  Also when trying to drop an item into the horizontal list instead of the main list it seems very touchy as well (won't make for a good user experience).  Thoughts?

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MQTgA/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more experimenting I have found the best way is to have the horizontal lists not part of the main list.  This way there are no double items being created when an item is dropped onto them and no touchiness when moving items around.

Here's a demo of what I'm going with looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/MQTgA/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because your top level unordered list ( the one with Items 1 - X) has the same class as the tables unordered list. If you change the top level , to a different class name it should stop double dropping the draggable. I hope I'm understanding your problem correctly, here is my change. [New code](http://jsfiddle.net/MQTgA/1/)

EDIT: Actually that won't help either because then you wont be able to drop into your upper lists. I think the issue is that as you are dragging and dropping jquery doesn't know which ul you actually want to drop into. You could try making all the elements a little bigger so the user would not have to finesse the draggable into the right spot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kyle. See the update above for some additional information.